# Cómo obtener correctamente datos de otra colección, emulando un join en Firebase desde Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

En lo que he investigado me he encontrado con que no es posible traer toda la información de la "tabla extendida" (por decirlo así) en una sola consulta en Firebase. De necesitarlo, debes hacer otras consultas hacia las otras colecciones, con el campo relacionado, algo así:

```
/// Esta función me permite obtener los datos de una factura (invoice)
Future<Document> fetchInvoiceById(String invoiceId) async {
    Document invoice;
    Branch branch;
    CashDrawer cashDrawer;
    Customer customer;
    Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();

    /// Obtengo los datos de "invoice"
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('documents')
        .document(invoiceId)
        .get()
        .then((document) async {
      /// Consulta para obtener el "customer".
      customer =
          await _customerApi.fetchCustomerById(document.data['customerId']);

      /// Consulta para obtener el "branch"
      branch =
          await _branchFirebaseApi.fetchBranchById(document.data['branchId']);

      /// Consulta para obtener el "cash drawer"
      cashDrawer = await _cashDrawerFirebaseApi
          .fetchCashDrawerById(document.data['cashDrawerId']);

      /// Genero el objeto de "invoice"
      invoice =
          Document.fromFireJson(invoiceId, branch, customer, cashDrawer, data);
    });

    return invoice;
  }
```

El problema con ello, es que los "awaits" hacen que se detenga la ejecución del bloque de código para esperar la respuesta de cada uno de sus futures, volviendo lenta la consulta. En este caso obtener una sola factura no es tanto el problema, pero si deseo obtener un listado de facturas por fechas, le toma demasiado tiempo resolverlo.

**Posible solución, pero como no me convence**

Una solución que no me parece del todo excelente, es en la cuál se debería poner los datos relevantes de "customer", "branch" y "cashDrawer" dentro del modelo de "invoice", para que así la única collección que deba consultar sea esta última. Esto ocasionaría que tenga problemas de consistencia en los datos de los objetos relacionados hacia la factura, pero como solución para ello, podría apoyarme en las **Cloud Functions** y solventar ese tipo de consistencia, generando funciones que actualicen la información en los objetos que guardan relación en cuanto se actualicen sus maestros.

Esto último no me convence, ya que hablamos de hacer otro desarrollo, cuando esperaría que haya una solución mas efectiva desde las mismas consultas, si es que lo hay, caso contrario me quedaría con esta solución.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Como lo mencionas , la solución correcta es usando Cloud functions para actualizar la data, debido a que no es una base de datos relacional, sino no-SQL, ese es el costo de este tipo de bd.

Comment: rayos, ya lo vi venir. Algún concejo para el modelamiento?

Comment: solo revisa esta serie de videos:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ

Comment: Listo @diegoveloper, muchas gracias por tus comentarios. Te invito a plantearlo como respuesta para dar por cerrada esta pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo mencionas ,la solución adecuada es usando Cloud functions para actualizar la data, debido a que no es una base de datos relacional, sino no-SQL, ese es el costo de este tipo de bd.

Para obtener más información sobre como estructurar tu base de datos correctamente, puedes ver esta serie de videos de Firebase

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI

Buena suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte diego. Es lo que me suponía. Gracias y suerte!